Inconsistent libssl.so.3 library paths in Rstudio server vs R
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS under WSL2, and running Rstudio server within a mamba environment with a short bash script that ensures that the correct environmental variables for the environment are set (R_HOME, RSTUDIO_WHICH_R, LD_LIBRARY_PATH). The console in Rstudio reports the same version of R as an equivalent command line, it has access to the correct packages, and reports the same PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH using Sys.getenv().
When I load the package (curl) on the command line I get:
> library(curl)
Using libcurl 8.10.1 with OpenSSL/3.3.2

But when I try the same on the Rstudio server console I get:
> library(curl)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘curl’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/me/mambaforge/envs/testwscall/lib/R/library/curl/libs/curl.so':
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.2.0' not found (required by /home/me/mambaforge/envs/testwscall/lib/R/library/curl/libs/../../../../libcurl.so.4)

For some reason Rstudio server - with the version of curl that is installed the mamba env - seems to be ending up pointing to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 instead of to `/home/me/mambaforge/envs/testwscall/lib/libssl.so.3'. Anyone got any ideas?
I tried:

reinstalling the curl library (didn't work)
using reticulate to reactivate the mamba envireonment inside the R session (that didn't work)
manually setting the environmental variables (didn't work)
softlink replacing /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 to point to /home/me/mambaforge/envs/testwscall/lib/libssl.so.3 (weirdly, that didn't work either)

On the command line within the mamba environment, openssl reports:
(testwscall) me:~/GitHub/wscall$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.3.2 3 Sep 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.3.2 3 Sep 2024)

So the command line R is learly picking up the correct library path to the 3.2.0 library, but Rstudio server isn't.
